# Need a new laptop to run Pro Tools 8 for around £600

Tags: pro-tools, laptop, purchase-advice

I'm currently running Pro Tools 8 on an six year old Dell laptop with 2gb ram. Which basically sucks.

So basically I want to get a new laptop or PC with a £600 budget. Preferably not a mac as i'm used to windows and a lot of the software is compatible for pc. Though if it's the most sensible option I won't mind switching.

The problem is I am currently saving to an external firewire hard drive, so will need a firewire port. However it looks like this has gone completely out of fashion. Are there any laptops out there which would still support this or maybe it would be more worthwhile just getting a new external hard drive.

Would basically any new laptop with 8gb ram be appropriate for running pro tools 8?

Thanks, Jamie

Answer (score 1):

Firewire ports are definitely hard to find on a PC laptop; I'd suggest looking for USB3 or eSATA instead.  You'd need a new external, though, but non-SSD hard drives are silly-cheap per Tb these days.

A couple of things extra to mention; firstly, PT8 is a 32-bit application, so its only ever going to be able to use about 3Gb at most of your RAM, even if you run a 64-bit version of Windows capable of accessing all of 8Gb.

Secondly, whatever version of Windows you wind up using, make sure it has working drivers for your existing souncard, as PT8 was tied to Digidesign or M-Audio hardware (depending on whether its HD, LE or MP).